# Storyboard - Open view programmatically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, xcode4.2

I am currently building an Iphone app that is using storyboards.  I know how to open new views with buttons via the ctrl+click method etc.  The problem I have is that when the user clicks the button, I need to do some calculations and processing, as well as opening a web connection to pull data so I can populate the table in the next view but the view opens first before I can do any of this.

What I'm running into is the view is loading long before I am finished connecting to the web service and have calculated and stored the data for the table in the next view, so it loads blank.  I need to either call the view in the button programmatically or somehow slow down the processes with some kind of "loading" screen but don't know how to do either.  I guess if its possible to fill the data in the table after the view loads, that could work as well. (if its possible)

Any tips or articles that can point me in the right direction would be appreciated.  I haven't found anything myself.

Thanks.

--connect method--

```
- (IBAction)connect:(id)sender {
//First begin by logging into the web service.

_email = self.logintxt.text;

//                            ---SOAP 1.1---
//large soap creation.  edited for privacy etc.
NSString *soapMsg = 
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"",_logintxt.text
 ];

//---print it to the Debugger Console for verification---
//NSLog(soapMsg);

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: 
              @""];
NSMutableURLRequest *req = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

//---set the headers---
NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [soapMsg length]];

[req addValue:@"" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Host"];
[req addValue:@"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[req addValue:@"" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
[req addValue:msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

//---set the HTTP method and body---
[req setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[req setHTTPBody: [soapMsg dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];



NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:req delegate:self];
if (conn) {
    XMLData = [NSMutableData data];     
}


[self performSelector:@selector(getXMLList) withObject:NULL afterDelay:2.0];
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"LoginSegue" sender:sender];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what I can suggest is to write the button action yourself. to achieve this you have to put stuff in your .h like

```
@interface MyClass : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UIButton *my_btn;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBoutlet UIButton *my_btn;

- (IBAction)MyBtnTapped:(id)sender;
```

in your .m remember to

```
  @synthesize my_btn;
```

then just link the action to your button by using IB, and voila'
the first step is done.

in your .m you can now implement a function MybtnTapped that deals with the data retrival and then opens up the new UIView fulfilled with your new data.

Comment: In addition to this, if you use performSegueWithIdentifier: as I specified above, you can use the storyboard flow as normal without needing to manipulate views manually.

Comment: This is kind of what xcode did for me with the ctrl+drag.  I created my button, drug the IBAction into my .h which created - (IBAction)connect:(id)sender {   This created the connection of the button and the method.  Then I created my segue to the next view.  If I am understanding the process correctly, this is the exact same process as the article Simon linked.. However this process calls the new view immediately when the button is clicked instead of waiting for the line performSegueWithIdentifier:@"LoginSegue" sender:sender];  Am I missing a step here?

Comment: Yes, but there isn't really much to it.  I create a soap msg, get back an XML of user information if the login is successful, parse it, then call a 2nd XML that I use to populate the next screen.  But none of this happens before the next screen is transitioned to.

Comment: ok the problem here is that you don't handle the connection, so that you can wait until the task has been performed to execute the performSegue..

Comment: you have to call [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"LoginSegue" sender:sender];
 in the delegate method of the NSURLConnection, which is called ONLY after the task has been completed

Comment: So I call it in the connectionDidFinishLoading delegate method?  I don't really see how that will effect anything since the view is changing before the connection code is even executed.  And what would the syntax be since I don't have an Id:sender in that method.  [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"LoginSegue" sender:sender]; - the 2nd sender gives an error.

Comment: that's the point. if you call [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"LoginSegue" sender:sender];
in the connectionDidFinishLoading the view will change only after the connection has completed.

Comment: what would the syntax be since I don't have an Id:sender in that method.  [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"LoginSegue" sender:sender]; - the 2nd sender gives an error.

Comment: OK.  I got it.  [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"LoginSegue" sender:self]; - worked.  Thanks tons.

Comment: you can use a ivar to accomplish the job: in you .h you can make a let's say id callBackSender and in the connect method you will assign the sender to the callBackSender, so that in the callback method your invocation will be [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"LoginSegue" sender:callBackSender];

Comment: You've likely got one view connected still from your button or whatever instead of wiring it up to a method in code, then calling the performSegueWithIdentifier.

Answer (score 2):

You can have your button or whatever linked to a method in your controller, and inside the method after your processing you can call **performSegueWithIdentifier:** to force the transition when you're done.  This will automatically still call **prepareForSegue:** before the view appears.

I've done something similar to check login details on a login page in my [tutorial here](http://maybelost.com/2011/12/tutorial-storyboard-app-with-core-data/).

Comment: Ive read your article and followed the steps.  My seque was already connected to the button's method under the press up action.  so that step didn't effect anything.  And adding in the line [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"LoginSegue" sender:sender]; didn't effect anything because the view is still being called long before any of the code or that line.

Comment: If you've done it right, your button should be connected to the button pressed method, and the two views should be connected by Right-click dragging from the Controller on the first view to the controller or whatever on the second.  There should be no connection directly from the button to the second view, otherwise that will happen before the code.